# Copy value from one dataframe to another based on multiple column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = 
  item  shop revenue
0   1   0   0.0
1   2   1   0.0
2   3   2   0.0

df2 =
  item  shop revenue
0   1   0   33
1   2   1   244
2   3   2   124
3   4   3   26
```

I want to map the value of revenue from `df2` based on the item and shop equality. I do this in a painful way first by combining two columns and using them as index. Then I map the value and finally I drop the extra columns.

```
df1['new_id']=df1["shop"].astype(str) +"_"+ df1["item"].astype(str)
df2['new_id']=df2["shop"].astype(str) +"_"+ df2["item"].astype(str)
df1 = df1.set_index("new_id")
df1.update(df2.set_index("new_id"))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1.drop(['new_id'],axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop(['new_id'],axis=1)

df1 =
   item shop revenue
0   1   0   33.0
1   2   1   244.0
2   3   2   124.0
```

There must a better and more concise way of doing this with a simpler code.
Could you please advise me on a better approach?

Comment: Are always in `df1.revenue` only `0` values?

Comment: any value. I used it just for illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by select 2 columns in `df1` and no `on` parameter for merge by intersection of columns:

```
df = df1[['item','shop']].merge(df2)
```

So it working same like:

```
df = df1[['item','shop']].merge(df2, on=['item','shop'])
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by 2 columns for `MultiIndex`:

```
df11 = df1.set_index(['item','shop'])
df11.update(df2.set_index(['item','shop']))
df = df11.reset_index()
```

Comment: ```df = df1[['item','shop']].merge(df2)``` will merge only the common rows. Other rowss will be left out. How do I add back the left out rows. The changed solution is good. Thanks.